# How to use Doctrine2 getScheduledEntityUpdates()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-update

`BudgetItem` is related as `ManyToOne` to `Budget` and to `Product`. Here are the 3 entities:

`BudgetItem`

```
<?php

namespace CDGBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use CDGBundle\Entity\Product;

/**
 * BudgetItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CDGBundle\Entity\Repository\BudgetItemRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class BudgetItem
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="meters", type="integer")
     */
    private $meters;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Budget", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $budget;

    /**
     * To String
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set budget
     *
     * @param integer $budget
     *
     * @return BudgetItem
     */
    public function setBudget(Budget $budget)
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get budget
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBudget()
    {
        return $this->budget;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param integer $product
     *
     * @return BudgetItem
     */
    public function setProduct(Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set meters
     *
     * @param integer $meters
     *
     * @return BudgetItem
     */
    public function setMeters($meters)
    {
        $this->meters = $meters;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get meters
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMeters()
    {
        return $this->meters;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return BudgetItem
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer;
     */
    public function decreaseProductMeters()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getMeters() - $this->getMeters();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPreEvents()
    {
        $this->getProduct()->setMeters($this->decreaseProductMeters());
    }

    public function onFlush(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            $entity->getProduct();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity)), $entity);
        }
    }
}
```

`Budget`

```
<?php

namespace CDGBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use CDGBundle\Entity\Customer;
use CDGBundle\Entity\BudgetItem;

/**
 * Budget
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CDGBundle\Entity\Repository\BudgetRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Budget
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="budgets")
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BudgetItem", mappedBy="budget", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $items;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="installment_rate", type="integer")
     */
    private $installmentRate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="check_for", type="integer")
     */
    private $checkFor;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="starts_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $startsAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deadline", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deadline;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_approved", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $isApproved;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="has_started", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $hasStarted;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="installment_rate_price", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $installmentRatePrice;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_budget_price", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalBudgetPrice;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="next_payment_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nextPaymentDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_paid", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $isPaid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="obs", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $obs;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->isPaid = 'n';
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set installmentRate
     *
     * @param integer $installmentRate
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setInstallmentRate($installmentRate)
    {
        $this->installmentRate = $installmentRate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get installmentRate
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getInstallmentRate()
    {
        return $this->installmentRate;
    }

    /**
     * Set checkFor
     *
     * @param integer $checkFor
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCheckFor($checkFor)
    {
        $this->checkFor = $checkFor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get checkFor
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCheckFor()
    {
        return $this->checkFor;
    }

    /**
     * Set startsAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startsAt
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setStartsAt($startsAt)
    {
        $this->startsAt = $startsAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startsAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartsAt()
    {
        return $this->startsAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set deadline
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deadline
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setDeadline($deadline)
    {
        $this->deadline = $deadline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deadline
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeadline()
    {
        return $this->deadline;
    }

    /**
     * Set isApproved
     *
     * @param string $isApproved
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setIsApproved($isApproved)
    {
        $this->isApproved = $isApproved;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isApproved
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsApproved()
    {
        return $this->isApproved;
    }

    /**
     * Set hasStarted
     *
     * @param string $hasStarted
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setHasStarted($hasStarted)
    {
        $this->hasStarted = $hasStarted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hasStarted
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHasStarted()
    {
        return $this->hasStarted;
    }

    /**
     * Set installmentRatePrice
     *
     * @param string $installmentRatePrice
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setInstallmentRatePrice($installmentRatePrice)
    {
        $this->installmentRatePrice = $installmentRatePrice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get installmentRatePrice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInstallmentRatePrice()
    {
        return $this->installmentRatePrice;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalBudgetPrice
     *
     * @param string $totalBudgetPrice
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setTotalBudgetPrice($totalBudgetPrice)
    {
        $this->totalBudgetPrice = $totalBudgetPrice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalBudgetPrice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTotalBudgetPrice()
    {
        return $this->totalBudgetPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Set nextPaymentDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $nextPaymentDate
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setNextPaymentDate($nextPaymentDate)
    {
        $this->nextPaymentDate = $nextPaymentDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nextPaymentDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getNextPaymentDate()
    {
        return $this->nextPaymentDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set isPaid
     *
     * @param string $isPaid
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setIsPaid($isPaid)
    {
        $this->isPaid = $isPaid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isPaid
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsPaid()
    {
        return $this->isPaid;
    }

    /**
     * Set obs
     *
     * @param string $obs
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setObs($obs)
    {
        $this->obs = $obs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get obs
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getObs()
    {
        return $this->obs;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param Customer $customer
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCustomer(Customer $customer = null)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * Add item
     *
     * @param BudgetItem $item
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function addItem(BudgetItem $item)
    {
        $item->setBudget($this);
        $this->items->add($item);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove item
     *
     * @param BudgetItem $item
     */
    public function removeItem(BudgetItem $item)
    {
        $this->items->removeElement($item);
    }

    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function generateNextPaymentDate()
    {
        if ($this->getStartsAt() !== null) {
            $date = new \DateTime($this->getStartsAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
            return $date->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getCheckFor() . 'D'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function calculateTotalBudgetPrice()
    {
        $totalBudgetPrice = 0;

        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $totalBudgetPrice += $item->getPrice();
        }

        return $totalBudgetPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function calculateInstallmentRatePrice()
    {
        return $this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice() / $this->getInstallmentRate();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreEvents()
    {
        $this->setNextPaymentDate($this->generateNextPaymentDate());
        $this->setInstallmentRatePrice($this->calculateInstallmentRatePrice());
        $this->setTotalBudgetPrice($this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice());
    }
}
```

`Product`

```
<?php

namespace CDGBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use CDGBundle\Entity\ProductType;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CDGBundle\Entity\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="meters", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $meters;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * To String
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param \CDGBundle\Entity\ProductType $type
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setType(ProductType $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return \CDGBundle\Entity\ProductType
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set meters
     *
     * @param integer $meters
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setMeters($meters)
    {
        $this->meters = $meters;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get meters
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMeters()
    {
        return $this->meters;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }   
}
```

`Product` is a collection form inside of `Budget`. It lists all the registered products to choose when registering a new budget. I have all the necessary JavaScript and a macro to show the form.

I need to update the total amount of `meters` from `Product` entity when EDITING an existing `Budget`. I have an `onFlush` method inside of `BudgetItem` for this:

```
public function onFlush(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        $entity->getItems();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity)), $entity);
    }
}
```

Now here is my problem. I do not know what to do inside of the `foreach` method. I need to do the same as I do in the `PrePersist` method, but I get different errors.

Inside of the loop, if I do `$entity->getItems()`, I get the error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getItems" of class "CDGBundle\Entity\BudgetItem".

If I do `$entity->getProduct()`, the error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getProduct" of class "CDGBundle\Entity\Budget".

Why does it magically change the entity? For God sake someone help me with this. Doctrine2 has a too complicated updating event.

Answer (score 0):

In a Doctrine listener, you always need to check the class of the entity, since every single updated items are stored in your getScheduledEntityUpdates() method.

The solution is to test if updated entity is an instance of Budget:

```
foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
    if ($entity instanceof Budget) {
        // $entity is a Budget entity
        // ... your code here
    }
}
```